# Bug pgfplots extra ticks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to add some extra ticks to a plot. However, they seem to bug out with formatting numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            grid=major,
            xmax=1,
            xmin=1e-1,
            extra x ticks={0.5},
            extra x tick style={log identify minor tick positions=true}
            ]
        \addplot {rnd};
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This grants the following result:

[image: result]

The extra ticks are placed on the correct location, but their label is completely wrong. If inserting '0.5' instead of '5e-1', this gives the same result.

Extra:

When I omit the 'extra tick' code, and use 'xticks = data', with the line

```
  \pgfplotsset{tick style=log identify minor tick positions=true}
```

before the plot code, this yields the same wrong result. The 'extra x tick' is useful because they're printed smaller then the major ticks.

Edited: code cleaned up, now only code to show the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. \simulation is a macro from a loaded table from pgfplotstable which reads data from a file in a different location. I'll change it a bit to get a working example in a minute. I'll check the updated manual first.

Comment: I converted it to a self-contained example and it's still the same result. I also checked the manual for pgfplots package, revision 1.8(2013/03/17) and it's still on page 238/239. It specifically looks at the 'log identify minor tick positions' key. It's the 3 plots (standard options, with/without minor tick identification).

Comment: I wouldn't write 'empirisch' and 'analytisch' in math mode, text looks better.

Comment: @Jake I now reduced it to the minimal version that still shows the bug. Torbjørn T.; indeed, I replaced a math number with the text and forgot to delete the $. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug which has been fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does look like a bug. As a workaround, you can set

```
extra x tick style={
    xticklabel={
        \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}
        \pgfmathprintnumber[sci, precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}
    }
}
```

to print the correct label:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,trees,positioning}
%\pgfplotsset{tick style=log identify minor tick positions=true}

% read data
\pgfplotstableset{
    col sep=comma
    }
\pgfplotstableread{P,Empiric,Analytic,PT
    1,1,1,1
    0.5,0.9998,0.999755859375,0.0625
    0.2,0.7233,0.703468589015119,0.0016
    0.1,0.207,0.192731013518619,0.0001
    0.05,0.03,0.0258145058547874,6.25e-06
    0.02,0.0016,0.0010448397034175,1.6e-07
    0.01,0.0002,7.60525098816179e-05,1e-08
    }\simulation

%plot
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            grid=major,
            x post scale = 1.5,
            xlabel= {channel bit error probability p},
            ylabel= {probability of decoding error},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel},
            every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
            xmax=1,
            xmin=1e-2,
            legend pos = south east,
            %xtick =data,
            xtick = {1e0,1e-1,1e-2},
            extra x ticks={2e-2,5e-2,2e-1,5e-1},
            extra x tick style={log identify minor tick positions=true,font=\footnotesize,
                    xticklabel={
            \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}
            \pgfmathprintnumber[sci, precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}
        }}
            ]

        \addplot table[domain=1e-2:1e0,x=P,y=Empiric] {\simulation};
        \addplot table[domain=1e-2:1e0,x=P,y=Analytic] {\simulation};
        \addplot [dashed] table[domain=1e-2:1e0,x=P,y=PT] {\simulation};

        \legend{$empirisch$,$analytisch$,$p^{t+1}$}
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. It's not that neat, but does the job.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug in `pgfplots`: `log identify minor tick positions=true` fails if x in [0.1,1] . I have fixed it in the developer version; will become part of the next stable.